# Drag and drop grid layout for angular2

Tags: angular

As a react developer, I recently took interest in Angular2. I use React-Grid-Layout `https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout`

Is there anything that is comparable to the above?

Comment: Check this one- https://bmorton.co.uk/angular/

Comment: There is a port to angular: https://github.com/katoid/angular-grid-layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can take a look at [there are some demo and i used it]

http://valor-software.com/ng2-dragula/ [demo] 
https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula [detail setup]

and 
     https://github.com/akserg/ng2-dnd [i never used it]

Comment: I don't see any grid example in dragula website

Answer (score 11):

Looking for the same (a user-editable grid layout), I found [Angular-Gridster](https://github.com/tiberiuzuld/angular-gridster2), based on [Gridster](http://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/). It's pure Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Now, the best option is definitely [Angular Material Drag n Drop](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api). The main advantage is this is developed by the same guys, who developed Angular.